# Find difference in CSV column python

Tags: python

I have two CSV with a column full of numbers. I have read those column from those files and kept it in variables (List1 and List2) using pandas.

List1 has more numbers than List2. For Example, List1 has 0 - 100 in a column and List2 has 0 - 50 in a column. I need to compare the numbers in List1 against List2 and print the result in another csv file.

It should compare each number from list 1 with list2 and if it list2 has that number then print it as "yes" otherwise "no" in a separate csv file.

Output in CSV as like:

```
Column1 Column2
0       Yes
1       Yes
2       Yes
51      No
52      No
```

I have read the csv and loaded the numbers in a variable. So 2 variables have those that has to be compared.

Comment: If the records begin matching at index 0 for both, then a simple iteration of the smallest list would suffice. Maybe smaller_list = min(list1, list2, key=lambda x: len(x)) <-- If that returns length of DF (CSV). Then just start at index 0 and compare. If you need to consult it with various sliding window operations, then that'd get a tad tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose both your `List1` and `List2` are pandas `Series`.

Then you can use `isin` method to check if the number is present in another list:

```
flag = List1.isin(List2).apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x else 'No')
```

Then you can get the desired output with

```
pd.concat([List1, flag], axis=1).to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the column 1 values into a set.  Then get the intersection of the two sets.  That will give you the common 'column 1' values.  Now for each common 1 value compare the corresponding value.

```
import csv

set1 = set()
set2 = set()
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
with open('set1', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        d1[row[0]] = row[1]
        set1.add(row[0])

with open('set2', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        d2[row[0]] = row[1]
        set2.add(row[0])

intersection = set1.intersection(set2)
print intersection
for i in intersection:
    print d1[i] == d2[i]
```

output:

```
set(['3', '4'])
True
False
```

set1

```
1 True
2 True
3 True
4 True
```

set2

```
3 True
4 False
5 False
6 False
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new field in the first data frame with a default value of No.
Iterate through the first data frame, check if the number exists in the second frame and mark the new column as Yes if exists.
Export the data frame to CSV.

The performance would be slow, so you may go down this route only if the data volume is less.